# Windows detects no ethernet cable is plugged when connected directly to modem

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet

I had a network setup which consisted of a modem and a
Wifi  router, where the router is connected to the modem, and all other device is connected to the router.

Recently my ISP offered to change the old modem to a newer modem+Wifi router combo, which had better performance than my old standalone router.
When migrating, every device connects to the modem properly, except for my PC, which detects no ethernet cable is plugged when it was connected directly to the modem. Sometime it got network access, but that only last about 10 seconds before windows said the cable is "unplugged" again.
On the modem side, the ethernet port was blinking green every one seconds. Sometimes it goes orange, but most of the time. It just stay blinking green.

I tried conneting the pc through the router then the modem and the PC connects to it fine. But that setup takes a lot of my space, not to mention the router is ancient.
I also tried reinstalling the driver using my MoBo included driver disk, but to no avail

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You may have auto negotiation disabled in your NIC. Modem and NIC tries different protocols. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/work/reference/configure-network-adapter-automatically-adjust-speed

Comment: I have checked that, and my setting was configured as Auto negotiate from the start... Must be something else..

Comment: Try to set it to correct speed explicitly. Do you use 8-wires patch cord 5U cat?

Comment: @user996142 I'll have to try that later. I don't know about the cabling. But it had worked for the last 3 years. Unless gigabit uses entirely different cable

Comment: Gigabit needs 8 wires while 100Mb may use 4 wires

Comment: I see, I'll try to force 100mb first, then if it works, then the cable is the issue. The cable was purchased before gigabit became prominent in my area

Comment: yep, have tried it in 100Mbps Half duplex, and now it works. but after checking, my cable was CAT 5e, so... i don't khow the problem

Comment: Are you sure all 8 wires are connected? There are devices to check it, or use simple multimeter.

Comment: That's something that i cant test easily, since my lan cable is routed to my modem 10 meters away through the ceiling.. However, I don't know whether my modem supports gigabit, but that should matter right?

Comment: If your modem does not support 1Gb and auto-negotiation then yes: the only way to set 100Mb explicitly

Answer (score 0):

If you are not getting a link light on the modem and/or PC you almost certainly have a fairly low level problem. For example, you could have a bad cable, or you could have a speed/duplex or MDI/MDX autonegotiation issue. It's also possible that you simply have a bad Ethernet port on either the modem or the PC and it's a coincidence that the modem was changed at the same time. Some of the first things that you can try are hooking the PC up to some other device or PC and see if you get link lights and to try hooking another PC up to the same Ethernet port on the new modem and see if that works. All of this would give more information that would help narrow down the issue.

In general it's often better to have separate modems and routers specifically because you can usually pick better quality ones as separate components than the combined units and you also have more ability to divide and conquer when troubleshooting.

Comment: I've tried to connect the new modem to my old router which then routed it to my PC, and the internet works. However when i take the router out of the equation, the pc internet stops working again. I tried this on my laptop, and it's fine, but it need a couple of minutes before getting recognized by windows